# Create subfolders, move files

Tags: finder, applescript

I'm trying to organize a bunch of audiobooks and would like to automate some of the work. I have just very basic knowledge of Applescript, but I can usually find a scriptlet online to do the work I want. This one I haven't gotten to work yet.
My files are like this:

Books/Author1/Book.mp3

Books/Author2 - Book.mp3

Books/Author3/Book.mp3

What I want to do is select the books that are not in an Author subfolder, create a subfolder with the Author name, rename the file to just the book title and finally move the book into the newly created folder. I have tried the following script and it works partly. It does everything except move the file at the end. It gives me an error saying: "error "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class." number -10010". Is there any way to change it so it will work? If it makes any difference, the files are on an attached drive (smb://NAS._smb._tcp-local/Audiobooks/Books). There are probably syntax errors for any purists, but as long as it works, I'm not picky :)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
    
    set containingFolder to container of item 1 of selectedFiles as alias
    
    repeat with f from 1 to count of selectedFiles
        set thisItem to item f of selectedFiles
        set oldName to thisItem's name
        
        set newFolderName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "-" in oldName) - 2) of oldName
        set newFileName to text ((get offset of "-" in oldName) + 2) thru end of oldName
        
        set name of thisItem to newFileName
        
        move newFileName to (make new folder at containingFolder with properties {name:newFolderName})
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the shell in such a case.

Open Terminal and enter `cd path/to/Audiobooks/Books`, then run

```
find . -type f -name '* - *' -maxdepth 1 \
    -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${1%% - *}"; mv "$1" "${1%% - *}/${1#* - }"' _ {} \;
```

PS: This assumes that you want to move all files in that folder and that Author and Title are always separated by `-` .

---

This uses `find` to find all matching (`-name '* - *'`) files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`-maxdepth 1`) and then executes the `bash ... \;` part on each of them. The executed part is basically a bash script which gets the filename in `$1` and then uses text substitution to extract author and title (`${1%% - *}` cuts off the part starting with `-`, `${1#* - }` cuts of the part ending with it).

Comment: Yes, the Author and Title are always separated by (space)-(space).
When you say move all the files, I assume you mean all the files that are single files, because there are also subfoldrs in the folder as shown in my original post.
I have never used the shell for this type of task, so I have no idea what the different parts of your command do! But I will try it and see what the results are. Thanks.

Comment: @Okotok All the files in the current directory, yes, but not any directories nor any files within these directories.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. For my learning, could I bother you to explain some parts of the command?
I gather that the first line makes a list of all the files in the directory that fit the pattern.
What makes the script go through the list? In other scripts, it would be something like “repeat from x to y”
"${1%% - *}/${1#* - }" This I don’t understand, the first part is the newly created dir but the second part??
And lastly why are these (_ {} \) needed?
If it’s too complicated to explain here, then I understand. I just like to learn.

Comment: You can run the first part (`find . -type f -name '* - *' -maxdepth 1`) on its own to see what it does, will explain in an edit.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the explaination and the solution!